# Make Buttons to Move Character Right and Left

Tags: unity, android, mobile

Can someone help me add mobile input controls for my game?  I've got this right now:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool facingRight = true;         // For determining which way the player is currently facing.
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool jump = false;               // Condition for whether the player should jump.


    public float moveForce = 365f;          // Amount of force added to move the player left and right.
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;             // The fastest the player can travel in the x axis.
    public AudioClip[] jumpClips;           // Array of clips for when the player jumps.
    public float jumpForce = 1000f;         // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
    public AudioClip[] taunts;              // Array of clips for when the player taunts.
    public float tauntProbability = 50f;    // Chance of a taunt happening.
    public float tauntDelay = 1f;           // Delay for when the taunt should happen.
    private float direction;
    private bool move;
    private float btnHorizontal;


    private int tauntIndex;                 // The index of the taunts array indicating the most recent taunt.
    private Transform groundCheck;          // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
    private bool grounded = false;          // Whether or not the player is grounded.
    private Animator anim;                  // Reference to the player's animator component.


    void Awake()
    {
        // Setting up references.
        groundCheck = transform.Find("groundCheck");
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        // The player is grounded if a linecast to the groundcheck position hits anything on the ground layer.
        grounded = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));  
    }


    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Cache the horizontal input.
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        // The Speed animator parameter is set to the absolute value of the horizontal input.
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(h));

        // If the player is changing direction (h has a different sign to velocity.x) or hasn't reached maxSpeed yet...
        if(h * GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < maxSpeed)
            // ... add a force to the player.
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.right * h * moveForce);

        // If the player's horizontal velocity is greater than the maxSpeed...
        if(Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x) > maxSpeed)
            // ... set the player's velocity to the maxSpeed in the x axis.
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x) * maxSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

        // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
        if(h > 0 && !facingRight)
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
        else if(h < 0 && facingRight)
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();

        // If the player should jump...
        if(jump)
        {
            // Set the Jump animator trigger parameter.
            anim.SetTrigger("Jump");

            // Play a random jump audio clip.
            int i = Random.Range(0, jumpClips.Length);
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(jumpClips[i], transform.position);

            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));

            // Make sure the player can't jump again until the jump conditions from Update are satisfied.
            jump = false;
        }
    }


    void Flip ()
    {
        // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
        facingRight = !facingRight;

        // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }


    public IEnumerator Taunt()
    {
        // Check the random chance of taunting.
        float tauntChance = Random.Range(0f, 100f);
        if(tauntChance > tauntProbability)
        {
            // Wait for tauntDelay number of seconds.
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(tauntDelay);

            // If there is no clip currently playing.
            if(!GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying)
            {
                // Choose a random, but different taunt.
                tauntIndex = TauntRandom();

                // Play the new taunt.
                GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = taunts[tauntIndex];
                GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            }
        }
    }


    int TauntRandom()
    {
        // Choose a random index of the taunts array.
        int i = Random.Range(0, taunts.Length);

        // If it's the same as the previous taunt...
        if(i == tauntIndex)
            // ... try another random taunt.
            return TauntRandom();
        else
            // Otherwise return this index.
            return i;
    }

    public void Jummp()
    {
        // If the jump button is pressed and the player is grounded then the player should jump.
        if (grounded)
            jump = true;
        else 
        {
            jump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As highlighted, the Standard Assets have used full libraries. There should be an example android project that provides an example of how it is used. Unity also provides information regarding the Event Manager, which is what I would use, as it allows you to link your image button to a behaviour (ie move ment) without needing to use additional assets. I'll provide a detailed answer when I can,but I won't have access to Unity for at least a week.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Step 1: Get the Unity Standard Assets

You want to implement one or another of the Cross Platform Input controls available in the standard assets package, probably the joysticks.

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351

## Step 2: Build your controls

If you look at the various sample scenes, such as 2dCharacter, CharacterFirstPerson, or CharacterThirdPerson, you'll find they have some form of mobile controls set up.  CharacterFirstPerson has DualTouchControls in under Scene > UI.  This is also a prefab, under CrossPlatformInput > Prefabs along with MobileSingleStickControl.

Drag one of those two prefabs into your scene, depending on what sort of controls you want.

You're done.

## Optional Step 3: Previewing

Now, the standard assets are set up to auto-detect if touch input is available (in the editor, it isn't).  If you want to check to see that it's working you need to edit two files:

1) MobileControlRig.cs and remove lines 69, 71-73
2) CrossPlatformInputManager.cs lines 26, 28-30

Three of the lines will be compiler control lines with a `#` at the front.  The fourth will be the "else" statement which we don't want (it'll undo the work of when the if is true and we want to fake it being true).

Comment: Hello yes i have this but i like make button for androin phone and add a button for left and right.

Comment: Somewhere in the Unity standard assets are some mobile controls, you're looking for the joysticks.  I forget where it's located or what the standard asset is called (I haven't used it in over two years).  Probably something like "mobile controls" or "first person input controller."  It'll already have everything set up exactly how you'll need it with on-screen joysticks.

Comment: Also, in the future, please make sure that your question contains the fact that you want something for mobile or android deployment.

Comment: I dont find that what do you think any code for this android button?

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351 "CrossPlatformInput"

Comment: This answer highlights issues with the question; but poor research effort on one users behalf should not mean partial answer for potential new users. Perhaps you could provide more detail on exactly what the user should do to make buttons? The Unity standard assets resource is quite diverse. You would obviously mean the *Cross Platform Input Manager*, but there is still more to be desired, before this actually answers the question.

Comment: @Gnemlock I was engaged in another task and was unable to do more than cursory research.  Updated the answer with more detail (it's literally "find the prefab, add to scene").